# Regex Date and Time Delimitter and Sort

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

My logs are getting stored in multiple Sun based unix servers.

So logs of Req1 might be in server1, Req2 and Req3 might be in server2 and then Req4 could be in server1 again. There is no proper sequence as it is stored based on what load balancer decides.

We use grep to get the data from all the servers. But problem is they are not sorted based on the time. What I want is to get the log file from all the servers as below but sort it based on the date and time.

**Edit**
Here is example for the question.

```
for (( i=1; i<=24; i++ )) do
    echo 'server1' $logfile $i 
    grep abd12453 /var/logs/$i.log
    echo 'server2' $logfile $i
    ssh server2 "grep 'abd12453' /var/logs/$i.log"
done
```

where abd12453 is the user based on which the log will be extracted.

The above commands combines logs of all files of both server and print it. like below.

```
server1 logfile1.log
06/13/2020 13:26:11.142 abd12453 server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log

server2 logfile1.log
06/13/2020 13:25:23.250 abd12453 server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log 
            
server1 logfile2.log
06/13/2020 13:15:35.142 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2.
    
server2 logfile2.log  
06/13/2020 13:14:42.156 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log
```

The above logs are all single lines along with username.

I need to sort the log data above based on date and time.

Required output should be

```
 server2 logfile2.log  
    06/13/2020 13:14:42.156 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log 

   server1 logfile2.log
    06/13/2020 13:15:35.142 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2.
    
  server2 logfile1.log
    06/13/2020 13:25:23.250 abd12453 server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log 

server1 logfile1.log
    06/13/2020 13:26:11.142 abd12453 server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (a few lines of contents of 2 or more `.log` files) and expected output so we can  help you. It's almost certainly not necessary to have/use a regexp that matches a date format.

Comment: You need to concatenate all filtered logs and then sort them by appropriate column(s). Thanks to the date-time format the numerical order or alphabetical order both correspond to the chronological order. You just need to choose ascending or descending sort.

Comment: guys i am sorry for not putting an example. can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

Since the date is not in YYYY/mm/dd format, that field will not produce the correct sort date order. Therefore, assuming that each entry in the output is separated by a newline, and that all have the same date value, then we can just
sort using only the time column ([3] - the 4th field of paragraph entry) by piping the result through this perl filter:

```
for (( i=1; i<=24; i++ )) do
    echo 'server1' $logfile $i
    grep abd12453 /var/logs/$i.log
    echo 'server2' $logfile $i
    ssh server2 "grep 'abd12453' /var/logs/$i.log"
done | perl -00e 'print reverse sort { (split(/\s+/,$b))[3] <=> (split(/\s+/,$a))[3] } <>'
```

will produce a time sorted result like this:

```
server2 logfile2.log
06/13/2020 13:14:42.156 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log

server1 logfile2.log
06/13/2020 13:15:35.142 abd12453 server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2. server 1 log data2.

server2 logfile1.log
06/13/2020 13:25:23.250 abd12453 server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log data1. server 2 log

server1 logfile1.log
06/13/2020 13:26:11.142 abd12453 server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log data1. server 1 log
```